# inverse of $f(x,y) = \log x(\tan y, \sec y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If we had a function $f(x,y) = \log x\ (\tan y, \sec y)$ is there anyway to find an inverse of it around the point $(1,2)$? I'm having troubles finding such a function $g$ with $g(5,1) = (0, 2)$

Comment: wouldn't be $g(x,y)=e^{-x}(\cos y,-\sin y)$?

Comment: if you mean inverse $\cos$ and $\sin$ then thats what I originally got. However, when calculating the derivative of $g$ I found that I get it undefined at $(0,1)$

Comment: Have you thought about what it means (algebraically or geometrically) to solve for $(x, y)$ in terms of $(u, v) = e^{x}(\cos y, \sin y)$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I did not and that solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @calculator: Glad to be of help. Just a friendly note: This isn't a discussion/chat site, but a question and answer site. Rather than editing your post into a new question, it's preferable to open a new question. That way there's one question per thread, and the existing answer refers to the attached question. The [site tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) may be useful, if you haven't come across it yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set $(u, v)= (e^x \cos(y), e^x \sin(y))$ so that $u= e^x \cos(y)$, $v= e^x \sin(y)$.  We want to solve those equations for x and y in terms of u and v.  Squaring and adding, $u^2+ v^2= e^{2x}$, $x= \frac{\ln(u^2+ v^2)}{2}$.  Dividing the first equation by the second, $\frac{v}{u}= \frac{e^x \cos(y)}{e^x \sin(y)}= \cot(y)$  so $y= {\rm arccot}\ (\frac{v}{u})$.

Comment: so that would make $g = (1/2 \log (u^2+v^2), arccot (v / u))$ but that doesn't give $g(0,1) = (0,pi/2)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $~1+\tan^2y=\sec^2y.~$ Use this relation to find $\ln x$.